# Can't get left and right arrows to show on slider

Tags: css, slider

website is tolitakeover.com ... i cant get the arrows to show on the slider they are partially there so it looks like theres something in the code that is covering it? not sure.. tried resizing the image didnt work.. also.. i havent attempted this yet but can someone tell me how to get the dots on the bottom to go the the left corner.. thanks

css for the slider only is..

```
/* Slider */
/* Browser Resets */
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  { outline: none; }

.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.flexslider a img { outline: none; border: none; }

.flexslider {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.flexslider .slides > li {
display: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
width: 90%;
display: block;
height: 50%;
margin:auto;

-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
.slides:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

html[xmlns] .slides { display: block; }
* html .slides { height: 1%; }

.flexslider {
position: relative;
zoom: 1;
padding: 10px;
background: #ffffff;

-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;

-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
}
.flex-container {
min-width: 150px;
width:100%;
margin-top:1%;
}

.flexslider .slides { zoom: 1; } 
.flex-direction-nav a {
display: block;
position: absolute;
margin: -17px 0 0 0;
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
top: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
text-indent: -9999px;

background-color: #82d344;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344),to 
(#51af34));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: '';
width: 9px;
height: 13px;
top: 11px;
left: 11px;
background: url('http://tolitakeover.com/images/arrows.png') no-repeat;
}

.flex-direction-nav a:after {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
top: 35px; 
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
right: -5px;

-webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
left: -5px;

-webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:before { background-position: -9px 0; left: 15px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:before { background-position: 0 0; }

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:after {
right: 0;
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
border-left: 5px solid #31611e;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:after {
left: 0;
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid #31611e;
}
.flexslider .flex-control-nav {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
bottom: -40px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
margin: 0 3px;
background-color: #b6b6b6 \9;

-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;

-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
 }

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
background-color: #82d344;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344), to
(#51af34));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);

-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct width, height and positioning properties. It would be simpler to separate the images for left and right arrows and correct the code for each. The code below fixes it.

```
media="screen"
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next::before {
background-position: -29px 0;
left: 0;

media="screen"
.flex-direction-nav a::before {
display: block;
position: absolute;
content: '';
width: 29px;
height: 30px;
top: 4px;
left: 4px;
background: url('http://tolitakeover.com/images/arrows.png') no-repeat;
z-index: 100;
```